# Creating vector graphics from web direct to print

Tags: printing

I would like to know what technologies are out there for generating high-resolution print-quality vector artwork from the web. And would like to know the pros and cons of each, please.

For example, a customer designs their own artwork for printing on some item using a combination of pre-defined images and free text. I want to output this in a 300dpi vector-based PDF that can be sent direct to a print production team who can then run it through the printer in whatever format without having to create the artwork.

Apologies if this has been asked, but I couldn't find an answer that clearly stated what technologies are there.

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: I imagine you're looking for [Processing](http://www.processing.org/), which is absolutely nuts. Here a [training site](http://www.learningprocessing.com/), [OpenProcessing](http://www.openprocessing.org/) (see the Create a Sketch top, right) and a [browser-based processing.js](http://processingjs.org/). That last one you'll find the web IDEs. Some really [talented people](http://reas.com/); 300dpi is nothing. It's fractal art. The [guy fwho started Etsy](http://levitated.net/gravityIndex.html) did it that, and started Etsy to sell his work. So, there you go. Hope that helps. `:)`

Comment: Here's another interesting site: http://colrd.com/ There's one I'm looking for that's pretty great, but I can't find it.

Comment: [Tinkercad](https://tinkercad.com/), [ThreeFab](http://blackjk3.github.com/threefab/).